# How can we add a Help button to CTaskDialog?

Tags: button, visual-c++, mfc, taskdialog

The standard `AfxMessageBox` allows us to include a **Help** button by using `MB_HELP`.

I can't work out how to do the same with [`CTaskDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctaskdialog-class?view=msvc-170#ctaskdialog)? Since, there is no official button ID for **Help** in the SDK:

```
enum _TASKDIALOG_COMMON_BUTTON_FLAGS
{
    TDCBF_OK_BUTTON            = 0x0001, // selected control return value IDOK
    TDCBF_YES_BUTTON           = 0x0002, // selected control return value IDYES
    TDCBF_NO_BUTTON            = 0x0004, // selected control return value IDNO
    TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON        = 0x0008, // selected control return value IDCANCEL
    TDCBF_RETRY_BUTTON         = 0x0010, // selected control return value IDRETRY
    TDCBF_CLOSE_BUTTON         = 0x0020  // selected control return value IDCLOSE
};
```

Yet, it does expose an [`OnHelp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctaskdialog-class?view=msvc-170#onhelp) method:

> The framework calls this method when the user requests help.

I assume, when they press <kbd>F1</kbd>.

---

#### Note

I realise I can use [`AddCommandControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctaskdialog-class?view=msvc-170#addcommandcontrol) and get around it that way. But I would prefer a standard button just like `AfxMessageBox` (CodeProject tutorial: [Add a **Help** Button to a `MessageBox`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562/Add-a-Help-Button-to-a-MessageBox)):

[image]